# Reasonable webpage file size

Tags: mobile, desktop-application, connection

What sort of file size is currently reasonable for a webpage? Considering a responsive design being served to both a desktop with a high-bandwidth connection and a slow connection mobile device.

Comment: It would all depend on the context of your site and how it's implemented. There's no universal answer to this.

Comment: This question doesn't have a clearly stated UX issue.  One could infer that page size affects the page's load time, which could negatively affect the user experience however that is not explicit.  You will get better quality answers if you clarify your question and focus on it's relevance to the user.  If you are truly interested in the total size of the page, you might try SO.

Comment: Charles - the UX issue is the load time for the user - see http://www.nngroup.com/articles/website-response-times/

Comment: True, but with the way web pages can be built now--namely strategic use of AJAX, the page size isn't necessarily a direct correlation to the *perceived* loading time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. You can try to find some relevant statistics in order to get some basis:

[image]

[source](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/average-web-page/)

Please also consider different types of devises: tablets, smart phones, etc. I would say the rule of thumb is still the same: try to decrease your webpage size as much as you can.

[image]

[source](http://blogs.synopsys.com/onthemove/2012/02/its-a-mobile-world/)

Who knows, maybe some internet-enabled fridge will say "Thank you" one day.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it should be **as small as is reasonable**.

Smaller webpages are generally **faster**; have a **better conversion**; a **better UX**; and are **cheaper** to serve.  The only downside to a smaller file size is that you have to have less in it.  You have to balance the two for your audience and your application.

For one application and audience, 2MB may be fine, but for another 50kb is too big.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said there's no right answer, it depends.  It's best to take an overall approach to optimization with tools like [Google's Page Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) and [Pingdom tools](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/).  It's easy to test often during the dev stage to constantly have an idea of what's going on and develop your own mental optimization heuristics.